# html_entity_decode is not working properly with json_encode ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

Hi I've this `Testing&amp;#039;s Ones` value stored in database now when I'm fetching my value into `text field` it is not showing like this `Testing's` and my code is

```
$loadingPlanName = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . $tableName . " WHERE $tablePrimaryKey='$loadingPlanId'";
$sqlResult = mysqli_query($dbCon, $loadingPlanName);
if (@mysqli_num_rows($sqlResult) > 0) {
     $jsonReturnArray["lpListingsData"] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlResult);
     if($jsonReturnArray["lpListingsData"]["loadingPlanName"]) {
          $jsonReturnArray["lpListingsData"]["loadingPlanName"] = html_entity_decode($jsonReturnArray["lpListingsData"]["loadingPlanName"]);
     }
}
echo json_encode($jsonReturnArray);
exit;
```

and my javascript/jquery code is

```
$("#loadingPlanName").val(data.lpListingsData.loadingPlanName);
```

but in `text field` it is not showing data properly the data should be in text filed `Testing's` instead of `Testing&amp;#039;s Ones`. I didn't understand why  `html_entity_decode` is not working.

Comment: text fields display only plain text

Comment: so what I've to do show proper data? because I'm using `html_entity_decode` at php side but its not working for me.

Comment: Why are you storing entities in the database in the first place? You should store the raw data, and convert it to entities when you need to display it in HTML.

Comment: I can't store raw data in database, so now is there any solution for it?